# Prove $(x^3, xy)$ = $(x)\cap(x^3,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Prove $(x^3, xy)$ = $(x)\cap(x^3,y)$ in $K[x,y]$. In a similar way find an irreducible decomposition for $I=(x^3, xy, y^2)$.

Here I tried in this way as:

Let $r \in (x^3, xy) $ then $r= ax^3+b xy $.

So, $r=x(ax^2+by)$ and this implies that $r\in (x)$. After this how to proceed. Show me the right way.

Comment: I doubt that $x^3 \in (x^3 y)$ ...

Comment: ... and $(x^3y) \subset (x)$, so $(x) \cap (x^3y) = (x^3y)$, perhaps a "," is missing and you mean $(x^3, xy) = (x) \cap (x^3, y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have shown, $r\in(x^3,xy)\implies r=ax^3+bxy=x(ax^2+by)\implies r\in(x)$,
and $r=a(x^3)+(bx)y\implies r\in(x^3,y)$, so $r\in(x)\cap(x^3,y)$ and therefore
$(x^3,xy)\subseteq(x)\cap(x^3,y)$.

Conversely, if $r\in(x)\cap(x^3,y)$, then $r=kx=lx^3+my$.  Then $x(k-lx^2)=my$, so $x\vert my$ and therefore $x\vert m$ since $x\not\mid y$ and x is irreducible.  Then $m=nx\implies r=lx^3+nxy=l(x^3)+n(xy)\in(x^3,xy)$, and therefore $(x)\cap(x^3,y)\subseteq(x^3,xy)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more conversational answer.

First, we have $(x^3, xy) \subset (x) \cap (x^3, y)$, because each of the generators $x^3$ and $xy$ is a multiple of $x$ (hence in $(x)$) and also in $(x^3,y)$: for the former, it is explicitly given, and for the latter, it's a multiple of $y$.

Second, we have $(x) \cap (x^3, y) \subset (x^3, xy)$, which is more work.  Suppose we have $f(x,y)$ on the left, so $f(x,y) = a(x,y)x^3 + b(x,y)y$ as an element of $(x^3, y)$.  If we can show that $b(x,y)$ is a multiple of $x$ then we are done, since then the second term is a multiple of $xy$.  Now, since $f(x,y) \in (x)$, we can add any multiple of $x$ to it to preserve this property, so we can forget about the first term and assume $f(x,y) = b(x,y) y$.  Since this is in $(x)$, and since $x$ is a prime polynomial, and since $y$ is *not* a multiple of $x$, it must be a factor of $b(x,y)$, as claimed.

For the second one, why don't you try the obvious thing (just add $(y^2)$ to the right side) and see if you can guess how it simplifies?  Once you have a conjectural decomposition the same game will work.

Comment: Is this decomposition unique?

Comment: $(x^3,xy)= (x)\cap (x^3, xy)$ is another decomposition.